# Less - Dynamic width of element on :hover and another element that depends on it

Tags: css, less

Simple html example:

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
```

It's css:

```
@left: 10%;
@right: 100% - @left;

div.parent {
    div {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
    }
    div.left {
        background-color: red;
        width: @left;
    }
    div.right {
        background-color: blue;
        width: @right;
    }
}
```

Right now left side is 10% width, and right side accordingly is 90% width.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EmAY9/1/)

**Now the question:** I need the left side on css :hover event to get width: 30%, and right side accordingly: width: 70%.

If I change my css to next one, I success to get left side dynamic.

```
.setLeftSide(){
    width: @left;
}

div.parent {
    div {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
    }
    div.left {
        background-color: red;
        @left: 30%;
        .setLeftSide();

        &:hover {
            @left: 50%;
            .setLeftSide();
        }
    }
    div.right {
        background-color: blue;
        /*width: @right;*/
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7jsx/3/)

But I don't get, how I get the right side to be dependent on the width of the left side...

**Note:** This is only the simple example of what I actually have in code (not my code, but the one, I have to support). Originally, right and left elements aren't going one after another, so CSS operators, like + or ~ won't help me. And I need to rely on LESS, as it was implemented, and I can't change the structure of the code.

Thanx for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `+` css selector ([info @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships)) that selects the next sibling of an element.

```
div.left:hover + div.right {
    width:70%;
}
```

It will allow you to change the width of the `.right` div when `.left` is hovered.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/b4Q2u/)**

*CSS :*

```
.parent div{
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
}
div.left {
    background: red;
    width: 10%;
}
div.right {
    background: blue;
    width: 90%;
}
div.left:hover {
    width:30%;
}
div.left:hover + div.right {
    width:70%;
}
```

Comment: @neoselcev then you can use the general sibling selector `~` see this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/b4Q2u/1/

Comment: **Edited the question**. You are right, but it doesn't answer the question.